# custom object context entity framework 6 and visual studio 2013

Tags: c#, entity-framework, visual-studio-2013

When I tried to search on the internet how to create custom classes for EF I get the following: set Code generation strategy: NONE

When I look in the properties of Model (Entity Framework 6 and Visual Studio 2013) I see only T4 and it is grayed out.

I was wondering how can I disable generation of classes?
what is the best way to re-define generated class?

Answer (score 1):

If you want to completely control how the layout is of the classes that are being used by EF, use code first.

It is discussed in detail here :
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/hh148150.aspx

Comment: no, i just want to stop classes from generation and write my own class from the scratch.

Comment: then it is not no, it is yes. Hence the term code first.

Comment: oh, im looking at tutorials they say generate classes, then set code generation strategy to NONE and re-write the class; that is exactly what i want to do. i have database first , not code first (because db exists already) BTW: it is for VS 2010, i use 2013 and EF6 and code generation strategy is T4 and grayed out so i cannot change that anymore :(

Comment: even then you can use code first there are options to reverse engineer the code first classes from an existing database.

Comment: it sounds too difficult. i just want to scale one of the properties by 10 or 100, that's it. (im working with WPF and observable collections,) but i cannot override property of re-define it unless i stop classes from auto generation.